Mutual Information of nonadjacent nodes in Bayesian Network
How do you compute the mutual information of two non-adjacent nodes in a Bayesian network?
In this case, what would $I(D;A)$ be? Would I need to take the conditional probabilities of all intemediate nodes on the path (e.g. $O$, $T$) into account? What about $I(D;S)$, where there are multiple paths?
My stats knowledge isn't the strongest so any help is much appreciated!

*I've borrowed the ASIA example from this Math Stack Exchange post, originally from A.E. Nicholson, N. Jitnah.
